# UIStatusBar inconsistency with orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a single view application (created from the iOS Template, nothing special)

There is 1 button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    // Toggle status bar hidden property
    BOOL hidden = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!hidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```

I first load the app.

[image]

Then hit the button.

[image]

**This is fine.**  I can work around the black space at the top.  Next tap the button again and rotate to landscape. Then tap the button once more.  It should look like this.

[image]

Finally rotate back to porttrait and tap the button.

[image]

In summay the issue is:

1. Hide the status bar
2. Swap the orentation (either to portrait or landscape)
3. Show the status bar
4. The status now bar covers the UI

I made a really [hacky workaround](https://gist.github.com/ce4f0cbbc84494c9b586), but I don't like it and Im sure it will break if Apple sort it out.

- Has anyone seen this before?
- Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced simmilar problems, my fix was on will rotate to orientation i would reshow the bar, 
and hide it on did rotate to orientation (or hide it again using performselector with delay)
What is happening to you is that when the device rotates, the view takes all the available space, it will also fill the space that used to contain the status bar

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // A workaround to stop the rotation filling up the status bar space
    // Show the status bar and then hide it straight after, (there is no flicker)
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) 
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        });
    }

    if (!_controlsHidden) [self resetFadeoutTimer];

    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat! I added my code, hope you dont mind?! Its still a little hacky, but I don't think I can get much better.

Comment: Happy to hear that, please if this solved your issue dont forget to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Xcode's Interface Builder (the graphical xib editor) to define your view with the search bar?  If so, in interface builder, select the view and in the right side bar, select the attributes inspector (the icon looks like a slider).  In the Simulated Metrics section, set the Status Bar value to not be 'None', Gray in this case to simulate the look of you app.  This will adjust the sizing of your view to accommodate the Status Bar.